# MongoDB add new object array field if not exists

Tags: c#, mongodb

Is it possible to add a new object array field in mongodb through c#? I have checked the addtoset but that requires the collection to have a field for my array.

I have a user module that creates users. Once the create button is clicked the output will be the below result. "User" collection/document

```
 {
     userId : 1
 }
```

I have added a credit module that will add a object of array for "User" collection/document once the add credit with year in it is clicked the array of value will append the "User" collection/document.
Below are my expected output.

```
{
   userId : 1,
   newArrayField : [
     {
        year: "2021",
        value: 2
     },
     {
        year: "2020",
        value: 5
     }
   ]
}
```

Comment: _"I have checked the addtoset but that requires the collection to have a field for my array."_ Can you tell what is your source (or, explain little more)?  It is not required to have an existing field when you use `$addToSet`.

Comment: So you need to update the document no!! so why dont you use `updateMany() or update()`

Comment: hello @prasad_ addtoset is looking for my array field so that it can add or change its value.

Comment: @varman okay, I think I will need to change the add user module to create also a field for my array upon creation? As what I'm trying to do is create a separate module that will add an array field to user.